# Why isn't there any decay process in which nuclei of elements other than Helium nucleus are ejected?

Tags: radioactivity

I think this might be a stupid question but I have this doubt regarding the radioactive decay.

I had gone through some introductory classes on alpha decay process few days ago and this question popped in my mind yesterday.

Almost all radioactive nuclei undergo "alpha decay" which is basically a Helium nucleus . So **why isn't there anything like carbon decay or hydrogen decay in which a carbon or a hydrogen nuclei is ejected ?**

Like heavier nuclei can break apart into lighter nuclei which should not be necessarily a Helium nucleus but I have never seen such a decay process.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_decay & https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=cluster+decay+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 5):

You're asking why something is true, but that thing is false. Proton decay  exists. Highly asymmetric fission exists. However, for nuclei near the line of stability, the dominant processes are (1) alpha decay and (2) moderately asymmetric fission. This is simply due to energetics. In the case of alpha decay, the alpha has an extremely high binding energy. In the case of fission, more symmetric fission releases more electrical potential energy. When the energy output of the decay is higher, the rate is higher, because the space of final states is bigger.

Comment: Proton *decay*???? What does the proton decay into?

Comment: Proton decay, as in delayed beta emission, as in decay e.g. of iron nuclei via the emission of protons. In contrast, free protons are stable and do not decay.